# Messaging via Libtorrent

Tags: bittorrent, libtorrent

[BEP50](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0050.html) describes Pub/Sub protocol over BitTorrent Protocol. Nevertheless, the BEP is not implemented in the LibTorrent. Are there any options for nodes to exchange messages via LibTorrent?